# Objective-C TouchesMoved - Very First Point Is Wrong, But Rest Are Fine

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:self.imageView];

        double width = 20.0f;
        double height = 20.0f;

        currentLocation.x = ((currentLocation.x - width / 2) < 0) ? 0 : (currentLocation.x - width / 2);
        currentLocation.y = ((currentLocation.y - height / 2) < 0) ? 0 : (currentLocation.y - height / 2);

        NSLog(@"X: %f Y: %f", currentLocation.x, currentLocation.y);
}
```

For some reason the above code gives me an incorrect point.y value only with the first value. How do I know this? Because when I simply slide my finger downwards slowly, the y point AT THE FIRST PRINTED POINT is essentially 20-50px higher usually, so for example it goes from 250.0px to 280.0px to 282 to 284 to 287 to 290. So why is the first point off by that much, its causing an annoying bug in my gesture.

Comment: Just try printing current location before explicitly setting its x & y values. Check the response. If this works correctly then the issue is in your arithmetic operation.

Comment: I just checked, it literally jumps from (182.500000, 140.000000) to (171.500000, 173.500000), and then only changes as its supposed to. How come the very first point I get is off by that much and when i simply slide down a little it jumps significantly?